# find all zeroes of $p(z) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{z^k}{k!}$

Tags: complex-analysis

show that all the zeroes of $$p(z) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{z^k}{k!}$$

where z is a complex number $z\in \Bbb{C}$

are inside the ring $$ \{\frac{n}{2e} < |z| <2n\}$$

Comment: Well it's certainly true for $n=1$.

Comment: Looks like an application of Rouché's theorem...